# How can you change the sort order in reader view?

Tags: sorting

I'm one of the many people jumping early from Google Reader in wake of the announcement to look for replacements.  I'm quite happy with Netvibes' reader view, which is almost exactly what I had with Reader.  The only thing missing that I actually used was the ability to change the sort order (I want oldest things to be first/on top).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to change order of sorting, according to Netvibes Documentation page:

http://documentation.netvibes.com/doku.php?id=main#reader_view

> In Reader View, the screen is divided in three main parts:
>       A: list of your tabs and feeds
>       B: selection and display options of the content
>       C: all the currently selected feed items
>       D: article action buttons
>
> The items are ordered by date, the newest at the top.
>
> It offers three different views: List, Expanded and Mosaic.